# Create a separate log file for each iteration in a for loop

Tags: matlab, logging, fopen

I just want to make a script which runs multiple files and stores their outputs in separate log files.

So I wrote the code by using `diary` to generate the output, but the `diary` function is only 1 log file and the output is updating in the same log file for remaining iterations. In my `testconfig_1` file, I have at present only print as the content.

Then I tried to use the `fopen` method, with this I am getting multiple log files but I don't understand how I can put that data into the log file which I have created through `fopen` after each run.

```
% with diary method
clear all;
diary on;
instring ='testconfig_';
for x = 1:3 
fprintf ('Simulation on testconfig_%d \n' , x);
test = [instring num2str(x)];
run(test);
diary testconfig_(x).log;
end

% without diary method
clear all;
diary on;
instring ='testconfig_';
for x = 1:3
fprintf ('Simulation on testconfig_%d \n', x);
test = [instring num2str(x)];
run(test);
fid = fopen(sprintf('testconfig_%d.log',x),'w');
end
```

I wanted to get `testconfig_1.log`, `testconfig_2.log`, `testconfig_3.log` and I wanted to print `in_testconfig_1`, `in_testconfig_2`, `in_testconfig_3` respectively

Comment: Have a look at the [Write data to text file example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf98f7) from the help. Let us know, when you encounter further problems.

Comment: What's the name of the one file the diary creates?

Comment: it is creating testconfig_(x).log

Comment: That makes sense from looking at the docs. Try `diary (['testconfig_' num2str(x) '.log'])`

Comment: the above inputs is working thanks for your necessary time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [command syntax](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html) to call the `diary` function.

```
% Command syntax
diary filename.log
% Equivalent function syntax
diary( 'filename.log' );
```

Notice that, when using command syntax, all arguments are treated as strings, despite not having any quote marks!

So when you do `diary testconfig_(x).log`, the equivalent is

```
diary( 'diary testconfig_(x).log' );
```

**All of your logs have the same filename, because `x` is never evaluated as the loop variable, it's always just part of a string!**

You are trying to create the strings with the loop variable in the name, for this you cannot use command syntax.

Instead, use function syntax like this:

```
filename = sprintf( 'diary testconfig_%d.log', x );
diary( filename ); % treat the filename variable as a variable, not a string
```

You don't have to declare the intermediate `filename` variable, and there are other ways to create the `filename` string, but I hope this demonstrates the issue.

Comment: in for loop if we add diary (['testconfig_' num2str(x) '.log']) then also it is generating that many number of log file and also copying the contents of the output

Comment: Yes, `diary(['testconfig_' num2str(x) '.log'])` is exactly the same as my suggested `diary( sprintf( 'diary testconfig_%d.log', x ) )`. As I said in the answer, there are other ways to create the `filename` string. If this helps answer your question, please consider marking it as accepted.